# How to consume the node stream returned by braintree

Tags: node.js, braintree

Braintree provides an api to search for the transactions. Braintree has provided an example, but i'm not aware how to read the node stream returned by braintree. Please look into the following code snippet:

```
var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
  search.paymentMethodToken().is("h337xg");
});

stream.pipe(someWritableStream);

//When I try to print the stream in console, I get the following result:

{ 
   _readableState:
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: true,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  searchResponse: { stream: [Circular], success: true },
  currentItem: 0,
  currentOffset: 0,
  bufferedResults: [] 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From nodejs stream documentation

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#apicontent

> A stream is an abstract interface implemented by various objects in Node. For >example a request to an HTTP server is a stream, as is stdout. Streams are >readable, writable, or both. All streams are instances of EventEmitter

You should make use of stream's data event to capture data as it is being received by the stream. The stream's end event is called when complete data is received from the steam

```
completeData = ""
someWritableStream.on("data", function(chunk){
    //Do Something With the chunk of data. You might want to concat the stream
    completeData += chunk;
});

someWritableStream.on("end", function(){
    //Do Something after the all the chunks are received.
    console.log(completeData);
});
```

Comment: Well. I did try parsing the object but unable to do so.
someWritableStream.on("end", function(){
    //Do Something after the all the chunks are received.
    console.log(completeData);
    JSON.parse(completeData);
});